# How do I enable hypervisor on Macbook for Windows Phone enmulator?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-emulator

I installed Windows 10 on Macbook and try to do Windows Phone Programming, however, windows complains I don't enable hypervisor on my Mac.

After I googling, I found my case is a bit different,

1. I don't use virtual machine, I installed windows 10 in my Macbook Air hard disk.
2. I cannot enable hypervisor in my Mac OSX. I removed the MacOSX partition as my hard disk doesn't have enough capacity, only 128GB.

How do I enable emulator then? Thanks for any suggestion.

Other information,

1. Macbook Air, 2014 later
2. Windows 10 professional
3. visual studio 2015 professional

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the hyper visor on the mac

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5597829

Core1090 said the following ...

I have found the following steps to be foolproof on my MacBook Pro Core i7 4th gen (Oct 2013)

My boot camp default boot is the Windows 8.1 disk.

1) POWER DOWN COMPLETELY  (Important)

2) Boot (holding Option) select Mac OSX 10.9 (You don't need to log in, just boot to sign-in screen)

3) Re-boot (do not power down, just restart. Apparently this preserves the hypervisor setting.)

4) (if Windows is not your default, make sure you select Windows during re-boot)

5) Hypervisor is now running and Hyper-V will now start VM's

For ad-hoc vm's I use VirtualBox. Current versions wont run vhdx disks but for simple configurations it is fast and has a better console.

I second an earlier request that Apple fix this and get us an update.

Comment: thanks. Actually, I don't have MacOS on my MacAir, therefore, no way for me to login MacOSX...

Comment: Are you running windows on bare metal on your MacAir? You will need to go into your BIOS and make sure Intel® Virtualization Technology VT is turned on.

Comment: thanks. I think Macbook Air cannot enter BIOS interface like PC, no such function.